# Which linear algebra to use for OpenGL in Haskell?

Tags: opengl, haskell, linear-algebra

I am trying to do some OpenGL programming in haskell. But i am confused by the current state of the libraries. [OpenGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL) uses the [Tensor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Tensor) package which only defines several vector types (but doesn't do so in a generic way). It doesn't seem to provide any Matrix implementations.

There are several other packages for linear algebra: [tensor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tensor) (note the lowercase T), [Vec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Vec), [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) which seem to be more complete than [Tensor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Tensor).

What i am searching for should at least contain common functions used in 3d and 2d graphics, have reasonable performance and should be compatible with [OpenGL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL) but i guess i'll have to change the library for that.

Comment: There's also [vect](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect), which has [OpenGL integration](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect-opengl) built-in.

Comment: **vect** does look usable. But i think it is far from being a nice (generic) haskell library. Actually it looks alot like [Java VecMath](http://java.net/projects/vecmath/) where every algorithm is declared for every vector type.

Comment: I think you should write your own. Being able to criticize other implementations means you're ready for it. I was in a similar situation once and tarried for a long while, but in the end it was time that was worth spending.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame, from vect [sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect-0.4.7/docs/src/Data-Vect-Float-Base.html): `instance Matrix Mat4 where ... inverse = error "inverse/Mat4: not implemented yet"`. That's not very useful...

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, sorry. HMatrix is the standard choice for things like this. It's very compatible, has a nice API, and is actually used for computer vision among other applications: http://dis.um.es/profesores/alberto/research.html

Comment: Unfortunately, hmatrix only works on vectors/matrices of things that are `Storable`, alias "have a C representation". If you want to use other or your own data types in there, you have to write a `Storable` instance yourself, which involves low-level pointer programming (or using [generic-storable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-storable)). Other package do not have this restriction, and might work on e.g. everything with a `Num` instance. If you only need standard numbers though, hmatrix might be the better (and probably way faster with operations implemented in C) alternative.

Comment: hmatrix also seems to be bound by the GPL license - which may pose a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same recently, and was especially annoyed that Tensor doesn't provide you with convenient functions for dot product, cross product, normalization etc.

As you pointed out, `vect` is "hardcoded" for `Float` and `Double`, and therfore cannot have useful typeclass instances like `Functor`, `Monoid` or `Applicative` - with those we would get a lot of operations "for free", e.g. addition: `(+) <$> v1 <*> v2`.

On `#haskell`, I was pointed to the [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) package. It is well-maintained and comes with a bunch of useful instances and functions.